# Local minimum in array, find $O(\log n)$ algorithm

Tags: algorithms, arrays

### Main Problem

Given an array $A[1...n]$ ($n \geq 3$) of distinct integers with at least a local minimum, output a local minimum.
A local minimum is an integer $1 < i < n$ such that $A[i-1] > A[i] < A[i+1]$.

Find an $O(\log n)$ algorithm or prove such an algorithm doesn't exist

#### Notes

It could be useful to have an $O(1)$ property to know if $A[i...j]$ has a local minimum. So far I know that:

1. if $[]>[+1]$ and $[−1]<[]$ then $[...]$ has a local minimum

#### Related Problems

1. $1$ and $n$ are also considered a local minimum

Certainly, in this case, the absolute minimum is also a local minimum

A solution is

```
int fun(int[] A, int i, int j)
------------------------------
 if i == j then
  | return i
 else
  | int m = floor((i+j)/2)
  | if A[m-1] > A[m] < A[m+1] then
  |  | return m
  | else if A[m] > A[m+1] then
  |  | return fun(A, m+1, j)
  | else
  |  | return fun(A, i, m-1)
  |  -
  -
```

The intuitive idea behind this algorithm is that:

```
    .
   /
  .
 /
.

=> local minimum on the left
```

```
.
 \
  .
   \
    .
=> local minimum on the right
```

```
  .
 / \
.   .
=> local minimum on both sides
```

2. $A[1] > A[2]$ and $A[n-1] < A[n]$

The previous solution also works in this case, but the proof is different

Comment: Can you explain those solutions ? (To avoid us repeating what you already know.)

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the case where A[1] < A[2] < A[m-1] < A[m] < A[m+1] < A[n-1] < A[n]

```
              o
             /.
            o .
         ...  .
         o    .
        /     .
       o      .
      /.      .
     o .      .
   ... .      .
  o    .      .
 /     .      .
o      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
1      m      n
```

Suppose p.a. that there exists a property that in $O(1)$ allows us to determine on which half to recur, i.e., by accessing the elements at index $l_1, l_2, ..., l_k$ we determine whether $A[1...m]$ has a local minimum or not. If the adversary uses the strategy $l'<l'' \implies A[l'] < A[l'']$, certainly the algorithm concludes that $l$ are not a local minimum.

If the algorithm concludes that $A[1...m]$ has a local minimum $h$, then $1 < h < m$ and $h \neq l ~ \forall l$. The adversary can always make $h$ not be a local minimum (i.e. with the different strategy $l'<l'' \implies A[l'] + n < A[l']$ and $A[h]$ such that it forms an increasing sequence).

Any other non-constant property $\Theta(f(n))$ makes the algorithm greater than $\Omega(\log n)$

$T(n) = T(n/2) + \Theta(f(n))$

Also, note that even with $k=m-4=\Theta(n)$ (that is, by accessing all elements in $A[1...m]$ except a certain $h$) the same absurdity applies, so a lower bound of the problem is $\Omega(n)$

By defining as a local minimum $1 \leq h \leq n$ the algorithm wins by choosing $h=1$.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, it is impossible to solve this in time $O(\log(n))$, as is shown by an adversary argument.

Take *any* minimum finding algorithm, and for every $A[i]$ value it queries, the value is $i$, except for the very last, which forms the only local minimum configuration. This obviously has complexity $\Theta(n)$, which is the worst case.

[You can replace the $i$ sequence by any other growing sequence of any length $\Omega(n)$.]